# Error message in R

Tags: r, regression

I installed the R package AER, from which you get the data PSID1982. Then I define this model:

```
data("PSID1982")
set.seed(15606)
selectedobs = sample.int(nrow(PSID1982),size = 400, replace = FALSE)
attach(PSID1982);
experiencesq = experience^2
dgender = 1*(gender=="male")
dmarried = 1*(married=="yes")
dunion = 1*(union=="yes")
dindustry = 1*(industry=="yes")

outreg = lm(log(wage) ~ experience + experiencesq + education + dgender + 
                        dmarried + dunion + dindustry)
```

And now I need to find out if the impact of the amount of work experience on the log(wage) is different for women compared to men, and what do I expect it to be intuitively?

I want to divide the set of data into 2 subsets being men and women and perform a linear regression each dataset, so I do this. but then I get this error message and I don't know how to fix this..... Btw i seriously suck at R its my last exercise i need to do...

```
outreg = lm(wage~ experience+experiencesq+education+dmarried+dunion+dindustry, 
            subset(PSID1982,gender=="male"))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = wage ~ experience + experiencesq +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'experiencesq')
```

Comment: when you create `experiencesq` or any other of those new variables in your workspace, then are _not_ associated with the `PSID1982` object, so you can cut the data in half with `subset` but the `experiencesq` vector will be full length. this is one reason why attach is discouraged

Comment: so what should i do? @rawr

Comment: @Latriuz Can't you just do something like the following `lm(log(wage) ~ experience + I(experience^2) + education + gender + married + union + industry, data = PSID1982)` ?  You could also subset `PSID1982` by gender if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Agree you should not use `attach` and instead of making a separate column of squared values (or following the advice of @steveb) you should use this call: `outreg = lm(log(wage) ~ poly( experience ,2)  + education  +  dmarried + dunion + dindustry, data= PSID1982, subset= gender=="male")`. The `poly` function is the proper way to use polynomial transformations. Avoids serious statistical errors.

Comment: @42- Just to understand better, how do `I(experience^2)` and `poly(experience, 2)` differ ?  Should `poly(...)` always be used over the other options ?

Comment: This has already been addressed on SO. Search on "poly orthogonal polynomials"